# How to hide link in Angular5/HTML when a certain condition is fulfilled

Tags: angular, html, hidden, angular-ng-if

I am working in Angular5/html. I am kind of stuck at one point.

I have a page where i can add different accounts. I have a link to remove those accounts. Now i want that link to show only when there is more than 1 account added. For only 1 account added i don`t want my account remove link to be shown.

How will i incorporate this condition in my code below? I mean if i use ngif but what will i do in response to ngif to hide the account removal link?

Also for condition in ngif can i specify it here in html (something like that that count is 1 or i is 0 as count is here to tell the number of account) or do i need to write function for it in my ts file.

```
<li *ngFor="let ac of Accounts; let i = index;">
  <div class="header">
    <h2>{{'account.title' | translate : { count: i + 1 } }}</h2>
    <a [routerLink]="" (click)="removeAccount(i)">{{'account.remove' | translate}}</a>
  </div>
  <account [data]="ac" [id]="i"><account>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `*ngIf` on the anchor tag.

We can get the number of accounts by using the length property of the array `Account.length` and then check to see if it is greater than `> 1`.

Below the anchor tag is only displayed if there is more than 1 element inside the `Accounts` array.

```
<li *ngFor="let ac of Accounts; let i = index;">
    <div class="header">
      <h2>{{'account.title' | translate : { count: i + 1 } }}</h2>
      <a *ngIf="Accounts.length > 1" [routerLink]="" (click)="removeAccount(i)">{{'account.remove' | translate}}</a>
    </div>
    <account [data]="ac" [id]="i">
      <account>
</li>
```